# scraping websites and Retrieving data or downloade existing website files

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-scraping, web

I want to scrape specific websites.For example in that website(https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cder/cliil/index.cfm) in index page when you select a data field(you can choose country) and in Country keyword you can choose USA it navigate search page( https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cder/cliil/dsp_Search.cfm ) I want to download search page.I want to scrape it.But there is no query string.How can I do this?

Are there any solution that I can post form in index with parameters?

Edited:

I use webrequest but it does not show page with data.Are my parameters is false?

here is my code

```
   System.Net.WebRequest request1 = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cder/cliil/dsp_Search.cfm");
            var Deger1 = "{'DataField':'COUNTRY','COUNTRY':'USA','Keywords':'','Submit':'Submit'}";
            request1.Method = "POST";

              byte[] byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Deger1);
            request1.ContentType = "text/xml";
            request1.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            Stream dataStream = request1.GetRequestStream();
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            dataStream.Close();
            System.Net.WebResponse response = request1.GetResponse();
            Console.WriteLine(((System.Net.HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, true);
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            response.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to make http requests with #c but to get your requirement fulfilled I think the below information is enough.

```
1. FormData={
    'DataField':'COUNTRY','COUNTRY':'USA','Keywords':'','Submit':'Submit'
}
2. You should make a post request with the below url along with the above form data. 

"https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cder/cliil/dsp_Search.cfm"
```

I've tested it in other language and found it working.

Btw, I've got above information by satisfying the below parameter in the search field using the following url:

```
url = "https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cder/cliil/index.cfm"

Search Fields:

1. Country 
2. USA
```

Comment: Thanks,I try it but it does not give page with data...I edited question and I add my code to end of question.Is my code is wrong?

Comment: No problem. For your consideration, two things you should bear in mind before processing the whole operation. You have to use `User-Agent` in the header and lastly the data are in json format. Thanks.